# R String manipulation with two vectors

Tags: r

Given a string f and two vectors:

```
f <- 'AJSDF'
vector1 <- c('2','3','5','13','2')
vector2 <- c('1','2','13','4','5')
```

how would you manipulate it to give a vector that looks like this:

```
c
# [1] "A1" "2" "J2" "3" "S13" "5" "D4" "13" "F5" "2"
```

Thanks

Comment: If think that last four elements should be `"D4"  "13"  "F5"  "2"`, otherwise I don't understand the rules.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I meant. I will edit it. Thank you for your answer it was perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
as.vector(rbind(paste0(unlist(strsplit(f, '')), vector2), vector1))
```

Comment: a short form(for lazy people) could be `c(rbind(paste0(unlist(strsplit(f, '')), vector2), vector1))`